# How to return a Neo4j schema with relationship names, from node names and to node names in one table?

Tags: neo4j, schema, relationship

I need to return a schema from a Neo4j database which contains all relationship labels, from-node labels and to-node labels. The table template shall be like this:

```
relationship labels, from-node labels, to-node labels
has_b,a,b
has_c,a,c
```

I noticed that the query `call db.schema.relTypeProperties` only returns limited fields, such as relType, propertyName, propertyTypes, mandatory. The fields missing are from-node labels and to-node labels.

BTW, [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/viewing-schema-data-with-apoc/) gives me a hint on solving my question. However, this method is proposed for returning nodes instead for relationships.

Comment: The table template might be confusing. What I need in the table are the 'from-node label' field and the 'to-node label' field.

Comment: You found the right article. It gives you all the relationship *types* between every couple of node *labels*.

Answer (score 1):

The one you're after is [apoc.meta.data](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.meta/apoc.meta.data/).